# Sort a list of arrays in alphabetical order using raptor?

Tags: raptor

Im trying to sort Sort a list of arrays in alphabetical order using raptor.
the arrays index is players[0-9] with a list of names. I cant figure out how to sort a string using this program.

Answer (score -1):

you should use the to_ascii Function in Raptor that will allow you to make an evaluation of the characters in a numerical way. I can post in a pic with one more rep...